# Gather a random sample of 5 from text file Python

Tags: python

I want to grab 5 *psuedorandom* items from a list containing 100,000. These list items are 25 characters long, currently my script is only getting the first characters (and they dont appear to be coming from the list).

**My code**

```
import random

with open("output.txt") as hashes:
    sample_five = random.sample(hashes, 5)

    print sample_five
```

**UPDATE** Throwing error of: `object of type 'file' has no len()` on line: `sample_five = random.sample(hashes, 5)`

**List in `output.txt`**

```
['KP9UF8GMKH0VNA1TURAAG6IHO','EQNUB4W1BYM7B5R6IWNWGEV4&','6QQSUUMCW9XPFVMQZUJKMAMW0','AZFUE8GWKHEVNO1TUEAADIHS','0DLWPEOD8345QASDZXCVBNHSD']
```

in `print sample_five` I want to output the list as shown above, but its outputting:

```
>>> [34378, 41139, 76739, 27686, 23880]
```

Can anyone see why it isnt grabbing (5) random list items from the list? Thanks

Comment: You are passing `xrange(100000)` to random.sample so of course it is selecting a sample from that. You may want `json.loads(hashes.read())` instead. Or get the numbers and grab the items yourself.

Comment: You're not actually using the text file. You need to sample from `hashes`, not `xrange`.

Comment: Can you show me? I tried removing xrange(100000) and put in hashes, but it threw an error of : "object of type 'file' has no len()"

Comment: you need to read from file...

Comment: @NamitSingal - appreciate the comment, can you please provide an answer?

Comment: is list in output.txt in exactly the same format as specified?

Comment: Yes it is exactly as shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80436/discussion-between-namit-singal-and-codetalk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
import ast
with open("output.txt") as hashes:
    input = ast.literal_eval(hashes.read())
    sample_five = random.sample(input, 5)

    print sample_five
```